# How to change dialog of CountryCodePicker (CCP)

Tags: java, android, xml

How can i change dialog of CountryCodePicker (CCP) title from Select a Country to Select a country or region. im using  CCP  library for Country Selector.  As you can see the below picture dialog title is Select a country.

[image: CCP]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well very simple, you check when the dialog is opened , get the title textview and change its text programmatically just like this:

```
CountryCodePicker cpp;
cpp=(CountryCodePicker) findViewById(R.id.yourid);


cpp.setDialogEventsListener(new CountryCodePicker.DialogEventsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCcpDialogOpen(Dialog dialog) {
                //your code
              TextView title =(TextView)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
              title.setText("Select Country or Region");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCcpDialogDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //your code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCcpDialogCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                //your code
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfect. Thank you @aryan agarwal

Comment: can you suggest kotlin way

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif no idea regarding kotlin

Comment: found it. posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin

```
binding.ccpPhone.setDialogEventsListener(object : DialogEventsListener {
            override fun onCcpDialogOpen(dialog: Dialog) {
                //your code
                dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView_title).text = "Title Here"
                /*dialog.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.cardViewRoot).background = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_white_bottom_sheet, null)
                //dialog size

                val width = (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.85).toInt()
                val height = (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.85).toInt()
                dialog.window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height)
                dialog.window?.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)*/
            }

            override fun onCcpDialogDismiss(dialogInterface: DialogInterface) {
                //your code
            }

            override fun onCcpDialogCancel(dialogInterface: DialogInterface) {
                //your code
            }
        })
```

[image]